# How to make the back button switch between tabs

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an application first showing a login screen which on a succesful login changes to a tab view with 3 tabs. Each tab is containing a different activity. When I switch between the tabs I would like the back button to return to the previous tab instead of the login screen.

How should the be done? I'm considering implementing onBackPressed on the tab view and remembering the tab-stack manually but I don't feel that is the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you have tabs created in class called Main.java. Create there method like this:

```
public void switchTab(int tab) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
    }
```

which will change current tab. Next in activity where you want to change navigation insert the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Main m = (Main)getParent();
    m.switchTab(0);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: This is pretty much the approach I considered except I thought onBackPressed should be overridden in the Main activity. This example always jumps to the first tab and I wanted to jump to the previous tab. So thats why I was wondering if it is neccessary to keep the tab "history" in stack manually of whether TabHost can manage that automatically.

Comment: You have to do it manualy. The easiest way is to create ArrayList<Integer> or something like this and in onBackPressed() method remove last element.